# Drupal Hook : no interaction between my module and Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook, boot, interaction

I well created and installed my module called "mymod". It's well detected by Drupal. However I'm not able to add interaction between my module and Drupal.

I'm starting with a very basic thing : `hook_boot()`. If I well understood this hook is called at each page loading.

For now I simply added the following code lines in my file "mymod_modules.module" :

```
function mymod_boot() {
        $step = 'ligne : '.LINE.' fichier : '.FILE;
        var_dump($step); die();
}
```

Absolutely nothing is append. Have I made a mistake or what's the thing that I haven't done?

Comment: Hook names need to match the name of the module - if the .info file is mymod_modules.info, change the function name to `mymod_modules_boot()`, and clear the cache

Comment: It's working good ! thankz for your lights !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot a part of the module name in the function. It's Working good with this code :

`function mymod_modules_boot() {
      $step = 'ligne : '.LINE.' fichier : '.FILE; var_dump($step); die();
}`